# write foreach inside calling class

Tags: php

hi im using this php code

```
$data = new $models([
    'number' => $row[0],
    'name' => $row[1],

]);
```

like this its working fine but what i want is that i dont know the keys 'number' and 'name' what if i want them come from array like this ..

```
$array = ['name','number','anything'];
$data = new $models([
    foreach($array as $key => $arr)
    {
       $arr => $row[$key];
    }
]);
```

how can i do something like this .. 
calling foreach inside creating new class .. 
thanks ..

Comment: You don't. Create the array first, assign it to a variable, and use that variable in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

 class Foo{}
 $className='Foo';
 $array = ['name','number','anything'];
 $row = ['name_v', 'number_v', 'anything_v'];
 $foo = new $className();

 foreach(array_combine($array, $row) as $k => $v){
   $foo->$k = $v;
 }

 print(json_encode($foo));
```

Answer (score 1):

So long as they have the same number of elements in the order that you want, just combine them:

```
$array = ['name', 'number', 'anything'];
$data  = new $models(array_combine($array, $row));
```

You can do it in one line:

```
$data  = new $models(array_combine(['name', 'number', 'anything'], $row));
```